# Are there natural conditions that could enable the formation of noble gas compounds?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, noble-gases

[Noble gases](http://www.chemicalelements.com/groups/noblegases.html) were considered to be inert until compounds that include them, such as [xenon trioxide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenon_trioxide) (as an example) were found.

My question is, what **natural** conditions allow the formation of noble gas compounds?

Comment: Natural? As in compounds you could find on Earth outside of a lab? I find that highly unlikely (other than clathrates), because most noble gas compounds are derived from the fluorides after direct exposure to fluorine, either with heating or light. Molecular fluorine is never found free because it is far too reactive, and it would be promptly consumed by anything *else* in the vicinity of the noble gas. The noble gas compounds themselves would be highly unstable and prone to decomposition. The only possibility I can think of is in extremely pressurized environments, perhaps in the mantle.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto yes, natural - I would appreciate any peer reviewed references that detail any research pertaining to the question.

Comment: I can give an example to make you know, one of the condition. Let us understand as to why $He_2$ molecule is not formed. This can be easily understood by calculating the attractive and repulsive forces when two helium atoms approach each other. Each helium atom has two electrons in its 1s-orbital. There are two attractive forces between the nucleus and the electrons of each atom. It has been found that when two helium atoms approach each other, new four attractive forces and five new repulsive forces come into play. Therefore, repulsive predominates and the potential energy of the system...

Comment: ...increases which leads to unstability. Thus, $He_2$ represents unstable state and a chemical bond is not formed between helium atoms.

Comment: I bet that electrical discharges in evacuated metal tubes, filled with noble gases and halogenes don't count as natural conditions, although the compounds formed were happily emitting in the uv :D

Comment: This is just thinking out loud, but could this type of reaction occur with lightning? @KlausWarzecha

Comment: @Amaterasu Honestly, I really don't know whether a situation like in an excimer laser might happen in the atmosphere under the extreme conditions of a lightning. I wouldn't even dare to speculate on that.

Comment: Here is a video about xenon in sand (theory) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fZ7_CyLpwPc

Answer (score 3):

As noticed in the comments, there are probably no natural conditions that would allow formation of noble gas compounds; although it should be noted that definition of 'natural' conditions should be specified. Lightning bolts surely carry enough energy to force such a reaction, but it is impossible for them to meet right mixture of gases, due to scarcity of both noble gases and super-strong oxidants and abundance of other substrates; as noted in comments (again), substrate able to create a compound with noble gas will create it with everything else first, and noble gas last.